# SVG Rendering Issue iOS

Tags: html, ios, svg

I'm trying to use an SVG layered sprite, but I'm running into a weird rendering issue on mobile Safari. I kind of attribute it to early adoption, but since it is rendering 95%, I was curious to see if anyone else might have a solution. I may just have to use PNGs or something, though.

Notice how on iOS, only two of the boxes have this glitchy behavior going on at the bottom, where the images are, technically, overlapping in the negative space. Also notice how the images are rendered in the wrong order. Everything is shifted one to the right.

Code sample to follow after the example image:

[image: SVG Issue]

**HTML**

```
<li>
    <a id="email" href="#">
        <img src="social-icons.svg#email" width="115" height="128" alt="E-mail" />
        </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a id="github" href="#">
        <img src="social-icons.svg#github" width="115" height="128" alt="GitHub" />
    </a>
</li>
...
```

**SCSS**

```
li
{
    display: inline;

    &:nth-child( 1 ):after,
    &:nth-child( 3 ):after
    {
        content: ' ';
        display: block;
    }

    @for $i from 1 through 6
    {
        &:nth-child( #{$i} ) a
        {
            @if $i > 1 { top: -30px; }
            @if $i > 3 { top: -60px; }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

**SVG**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

    <svg:style xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" type="text/css">
        .i { display: none; }
        .i:target { display: block; }
    </svg:style>

    <svg:svg class="i" id="email" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 458 512" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        ...
    </svg:svg>

    <svg:svg class="i" id="facebook" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 458 512" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        ...
    </svg:svg>
</svg:svg>
```

I'm only posing the question because, as I stated, it seems to be working, with a few minor glitches. Why might the icons rendering the wrong, and sometimes partial, images?

Is there anything I can try before I give up and resort to raster images? So far, I've just been trying all kinds of random properties--margin, relative positioning, line height, etc.--but whenever I reduce the spacing between the rows it renders glitchy. If I don't and leave the space between them, it renders fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the rendering issue on iOS by changing the HTML source. Instead of using `img` elements, I switched them to actual SVG elements, and it works!

Interestingly, if I only changed the first one, everything rendered fine, but I ended up switching them all for consistency sake.

Changed this:

```
<li>
    <a id="email" href="#">
        <img src="icons/queue-icons.svg#email" width="115" height="128" alt="E-mail" />
    </a>
</li>
```

To this:

```
<li>
    <a id="email" href="#">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 115 128">
            <use xlink:href="/icons/queue-icons.svg#email"></use>
        </svg>
    </a>
</li>
```

Thanks to [this article on CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts/) for providing me with some additional information.